# How to set up redirects for category paginated pages after adding /category/ to permalink

Tags: regex, redirect

We have a site using [WPML](https://wpml.org/) and the category archives like `/categoryname/page/2` weren't working in the secondary language. I added /category/ to the permalink and now the pagination works, but I need help getting the paginated archive links to 301 redirect.

1. I set up manual redirects for the main category archives using the [Redirection plugin](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/):

   - **Ex**: `/categoryname/` redirects to: `/category/categoryname/`
2. I need help with redirecting the paginated pages in the category archive.

   - **Ex**: `http://example.com/categoryname/page/1` redirects to `http://example.com/category/categoryname/page/1`
3. Single posts haven't been redirected because they work fine with `/category/` in the permalink, and I'd love to keep it as-is if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your `.htaccess`, in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)/page/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category/$1/? [R=301,L]
```

Your default `.htaccess` created from WordPress should now look like the following:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# Custom RewriteRule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)/page/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /category/$1/? [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan for answering! Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. The redirect doesn't happen.

Comment: @RebeccaM Updated answer through the `.htaccess` route. Let me know if that works.